# My computer is running hotter then usual? Do I need to install something?

Tags: 12.04, drivers, graphics

I'm new to ubuntu and so far I've not had great experiences. Since I installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my computer it seems like it's running hotter. What I mean by that is my fan is constantly on and running loud, even when idle at the desktop with no programs opened, even straight from boot and several hours after boot. I opened terminal and did the TOP thing and I wasn't running any CPU power and i was using like 0.2 RAM.

I had 12.10 at first but figured since there is a LTS group for 12.04 I'd give it a try and the problem remained..   this problem never existed when I previously ran Windows 7.
I even went as far as to take apart my laptop and blow it out and clean the fan, ect.

I **was told** there is a certain problem with ubuntu running right off the graphics card and that there is a fix for it, to make it run cooler. I have yet to find this fix so any helpful advice on the matter would be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend fixing the pcie aspm kernel power regression (instructions at http://www.webupd8.org/2011/06/linux-kernel-power-issue-fix.html) and applying the tweaks at (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagement/PowerSavingTweaks). These helped me a lot personally.

Also make sure you have a proprietary graphics driver installed; open-source drivers don't work as well.

If things are still running hot, maybe use a lighter desktop environment such as Xfce.

Comment: that pcie aspm kernel thing didn't help at all, i actually did that twice before and people keep recommending me to that but it never helped. 

and for the proprietary graphics thing, when i go into addition drviers it says No proprietary drivers are in use on this system.
and i have no idea how to install them or the right ones.

i've watched a few videos and read a few things but i can't seem to find anything helpful to me "12.04 LTS"

Comment: Well Windows 7 is a solution :) Can you include more detailed info your question, such as the what hardware are you using and whether you are using 32-bit or 64-bit ubuntu

Comment: i'm using 32-bit, as far as hardware i'm not sure exactly, but i can tell you i'm not on a cheap wal-mart computer.  i know i have 6GB of ram, 750GB hd,  ati firepro graphics card not sure the ghz or anything very specific and i'm running an intel 2 quadcore

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help much, but I'll try. Did you use to have Windows 7 32-bit or 64-bit? From your specs, it seems like your computer is built for 64-bit; if this is the case, you should install Ubuntu 64-bit. Also, do some research to see if ati firepro is known to work well with Ubuntu. Last but not least, you could try installing Ubuntu 12.10